# Why there is no reabsorption in LED crystals?

Tags: optics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

Can you explain to me please, why there is no reabsorption in crystals which are used as LEDs?  Because the energy of emitted light is the same as the band gap of the semiconductor - it should be absorbed. Why is it not?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are constantly providing energy to the LED. The electrical energy has to be expended. This is similar to atomic fluorescence phenomenon. You shine a particular wavelength on gas phase atoms which they absorb, the excited atoms emit precisely the same wavelength. This process goes on as long as you provide the right energy.

Comment: Yes some is reabsorbed after emission, but as the population of excited atoms is very high and is constantly replenished most of the photons escape.

Answer (score 1):

There is always absorption in an LED, this rate however is much lower than that at which photons is emitted and thus there is a net emission of photons.